# How do I provide Ack with the directory I want to search?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I would like to use the linux command line tool `ack` but there is one thing stopping me from using it and that is that I cannot figure out how to tell it where to start searching from. I would like to start to replace my complex `find`/`xargs`/`grep` commands with `ack` but if I cannot tell it where to start to search from I cannot use it.

For instance I am running a simulation in one directory but I would like to tell `ack` to search a code library from somewhere else without having to change to that directory to invoke `ack`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can provide the directory as an argument; only if you give it zero arguments past your pattern will it look in the current directory instead of where you ask it.

```
ack MySymbol ../src
```

Comment: I'll be damned... I didn't really get that from the help and I didn't see any examples using it that way... Thank you!

Comment: +1 damned...I didn't find it either and googled it here... So thank you for asking

Answer (score 2):

This is in the help

```
>ack --help-types
or
>ack --help
Usage: ack [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILES OR DIRECTORIES]
```